# Latitude and Longitude showing as 0 in Android

Tags: android, gps, location, latitude-longitude

```
  ************* TrackGPS.java *****************************  

    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;

    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.provider.Settings;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    /**
     * Created by ANQ on 8/8/2016.
     */

    public class TrackGPS extends Service implements LocationListener {

        private final Context mContext;


        boolean checkGPS = false;


        boolean checkNetwork = false;

        boolean canGetLocation = false;

        Location loc;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;


        private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;


        private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;
        protected LocationManager locationManager;

        public TrackGPS(Context mContext) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            getLocation();
        }

        private Location getLocation() {

            try {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // getting GPS status
                checkGPS = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                // getting network status
                checkNetwork = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!checkGPS && !checkNetwork) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Service Provider Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    this.canGetLocation = true;
                    // First get location from Network Provider
                    if (checkNetwork) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        try {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("Network", "Network");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                loc = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                            }

                            if (loc != null) {
                                latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                                longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                        catch(SecurityException e){

                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (checkGPS) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"GPS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (loc == null) {
                        try {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                loc = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (loc != null) {
                                    latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (SecurityException e) {

                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return loc;
        }

        public double getLongitude() {
            if (loc != null) {
                longitude = loc.getLongitude();
            }
            return longitude;
        }

        public double getLatitude() {
            if (loc != null) {
                latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            }
            return latitude;
        }

        public boolean canGetLocation() {
            return this.canGetLocation;
        }

        public void showSettingsAlert() {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);


            alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Not Enabled");

            alertDialog.setMessage("Do you wants to turn On GPS");


            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });


            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });


            alertDialog.show();
        }


        public void stopUsingGPS() {
            if (locationManager != null) {

                locationManager.removeUpdates(TrackGPS.this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    }






************* MainActivity.java ****************

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private Button b_get;
        private TrackGPS gps;
        double longitude;
        double latitude;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            b_get = (Button)findViewById(R.id.get);



            b_get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    gps = new TrackGPS(MainActivity.this);


                    if(gps.canGetLocation()){


                        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                        latitude = gps .getLatitude();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Longitude:"+Double.toString(longitude)+"\nLatitude:"+Double.toString(latitude),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            gps.stopUsingGPS();
        }
    }
```

When i am running the application the latitude and longitude is showing as 0.0, i am using android marshmallow to test this application. "http://clover.studio/2016/08/09/getting-current-location-in-android-using-location-manager/" this is the link that i have used to create the application.

Comment: try to give location and other permission for M 6.0 ..

Comment: try GoogleApiClient to get location  -- Please look this http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/

Comment: You can try fused location service to implement that or you can create a background service if you want locations through the app

Comment: There are problems with the code. Have a look at e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082062/code-will-only-return-0-0-0-0-gps-coordinate-while-throwing-nullpointerexceptio/43082164#43082164), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554482/not-getting-latitude-and-longitude-from-background-service#40555003), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747349/getlastknownlocation-return-null-using-gps-provider-and-network-provider#36752030) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307587/not-gettting-accurate-location-in-some-android-phones#36312624) for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please manage required permission for marshmallow.

First you add  this permission in manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

After in your activity First declare two variable like this,

```
 private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 1;
 String mPermission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
```

After in onCreate method

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= 23) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(mPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{mPermission,
                    },
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            *here manage your code if permission already access
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's my pleasure sir.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the background service to detect current location at time interval

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
public class LocationBackGroundService extends Service implements LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationBackGroundService";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 10;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 10;

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    Context mCOntext;

    public void LocationBackGroundService(Context mContext) {
        this.mCOntext = mContext;
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {

        }
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }

    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        Toast.makeText(this,"OnConnection Suspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"OnConnection Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
            mCurrentLocation = location;
            String lat = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
            String lng = String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

            ConstantFunction.saveStatus(this, ConstantVariables.CURRENT_LATITUDE, lat);
            ConstantFunction.saveStatus(this, ConstantVariables.CURRENT_LONGTITUDE, lng);
            System.out.println("First Condition Hit");
            System.out.println("Lat::-- " + lat + "\n" + "LONG::--" + lng);
        }

        System.out.println("Lat::-- " + location.getLatitude() + "\n" + "LONG::--" + location.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

Put this code in seperate java file named `LocationBackGroundService.java` and call it in your `MainActivity` like this `startService(new Intent(this, LocationBackGroundService.class));` and don't forget to add it in menifest like this `<service android:name="LocationBackGroundService"></service>`

Comment: where should is place this code sir in the MainActivity or somewhere else.also if you can describe in short what this code does since i am a novice?

Comment: and also you have to add a run time permission for starting a service