# Webview location in Android 6.0

Tags: android, webview, location

I'm developing an android application (webview). One of the functionalities is required for geolocation enabled in order to detect my current location in BaiduMap. 
I have tested with Android 4.4 , the webview is working fine and BaiduMap can detect my current location. For Android 6.0,  Baidu Map cannot detect my precise location although i have set the targetSDK=22 in my build.gradle
Could someone help, i really appreciate!

Comment: I guess you have to ask permission, have a look in this link: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: please share the code when you ask a question else answer would be just a guess, like have you declared permissions in manifest and runtime for 6.0????

Comment: added link on my comment plz check.

Comment: You have not manage runtime permission, Please check my ans in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154468/latitude-and-longitude-showing-as-0-in-android/43154670#43154670

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the location is enabled in the settings-> apps-> app permissions -> location